# Extract all the text from a special type of URL using Python

Tags: python, text-extraction, xbrl

I am trying to extract all the text from some SEC filings with their URLs. I can get the job done for most URLs until I run into some special type of URLs (seems to be related to XBRL).

url_1 that my code works:
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1044378/000156459020025525/bioc-10q_20200331.htm

url_2 that my code doesn't work:
https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/1002590/000156459020020844/sgu-10q_20200331.htm

Here is my code:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
    html = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for table in soup.find_all("table"):
    table.decompose()
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()  
text = soup.get_text()
print (text)
```

I am new to Python, and learned this via some youtube videos, could someone help me on how to extract all the text for the url_2.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You are right in that url_2 is an iXBRL link. Fortunately, the link to the plain vanilla filing is hiding right there.

Try this:

```
url_2 = "https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/1002590/000156459020020844/sgu-10q_20200331.htm"
url_3=url.replace('ix?doc=/','')
url_3
```

Output:

```
'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1002590/000156459020020844/sgu-10q_20200331.htm'
```

Just use this as your target url.

Comment: also you can just put that as a if statement, so it would automatically check all links you are trying to find: `if( 'ix?doc=/' in url)`

Comment: @user12167490 If we're done, don't forget to accept the answer,please.